# XSLT Attribute string test

Tags: xml, testing, xslt, attributes

I'm editing some existing XSLT so I can change the display of the content to appear in tabs.  I've used one of the string variables to assign a div id for individual styling.  I'm now trying to test that new id attribute for the name of the first tab and then setting the style to `display:block` for that one tab. I know the WHEN condition is processing because a style is being applied to the div, but it's all `display:none`.

I am not particularly good at XSLT (steep learning curve) but I got all but this latter bit to work and I figure it's just because I don't know the proper syntax.  Here's the block I'm working with. Showing the whole div block but it's the first dozen lines that matter:

```
  <div class="container">
<xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($tmpTitle, 1, 5)"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@id='First'">
             <xsl:attribute name="style">display:block</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:attribute name="style">display:none</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

<li>

    <h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="$tmpTitle"/>
    </h2>

    <xsl:if test="$listType != ''">
        <a class="guidelinesLink">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="link"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="link/url-text"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:if>


    <ul class="itemList">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//item[../title = $tmpTitle or ../title-ddl = $tmpTitle]">
            <xsl:sort select="title"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ul>

</li>
</div>
```

Comment: You can’t test the `id` attribute; it only exists in the result tree. You can either test the result of another substring() call or use a variable to store the result of the substring call and test that (and use it as the value of `id`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML that you are transforming does not have an `@id` who's value is equal to `First`, so the `test="@id='First'"` will always be false, and will fall down to the `xsl:otherwise`.

Instead, bind the value that you are using to create the `@id` to a variable and use that variable both to create the `@id` attribute and to determine what value to assign to the `@style`.

Also, if you are always going to be creating the `@style` attribute, then you can move the `xsl:choose` inside the `xsl:attribute` and only declare it once:

```
<div class="container">
  <xsl:variable name="identifier" select="substring($tmpTitle, 1, 5)"/>
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="$identifier"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="style">
    <xsl:text>display:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$identifier='First'">
        <xsl:text>block</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>none</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: Thanks this is great on 3 fronts: 1) It fixed my problem 2) I understand it and 3) I learned something today!  Thanks for the help.